# Multiple Errors on my PartnerBot Discord Py

Tags: python, discord.py

Ive Got This Piece of Code for my Partnerbot that i am coding

```
@client.command()
async def partner(ctx):
    form = Form(ctx, "Partnership Request")
    form.add_question(
    "What's the invite link to your server?", # The question which it will ask
    "invitelink", # What the form will call the result of this question
    "invite" # The type the response should be
)
form.add_question(
    "What's a description of your server?",
    "description"
)
form.add_question(
    "What's your server's advertisement?",
    "advertisement"
)
results = await form.start()
embed = discord.Embed(
    title=f"Partnership Request from {results.invitelink.guild.name}",
    description=f"**Description:** {results.description}",
    )
embed.set_thumbnail(url=results.invitelink.guild.icon_url)
embed.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
partnershipreq = client.get_channel(843569943807393816)
prompt = await partnershipreq.send(embed=embed)
confirm = ReactConfirm(message=prompt, bot=bot,user = ctx.message.author)
accepted = await confirm.start()
if accepted:
    partners = client.get_channel(843569943807393815)
    em = discord.Embed(title=results.invitelink.guild.name, description=results.advertisement, 
    color=0x2F3136)
    em.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    em.set_thumbnail(url=results.invitelink.guild.icon_url)
    await partners.send(embed=em)
```

> Everytime i try to accept or deny the partner request nothing happens and the code give me following Errors:
> I Read both Docs
> I Tried to understand the code
> I realised that i hate my self xD

```
"C:\Users\MCPEG\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\forms\reactions.py", line 96, in start
r = await self._bot.wait_for(
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.bot' has no attribute 'wait_for'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MCPEG\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\MCPEG\Desktop\bot\partnerbot.py", line 37, in partner
    accepted = await confirm.start()
   File "C:\Users\MCPEG\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\forms\reactions.py", line 100, in start
return await message.edit("Timeout!")
TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MCPEG\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File
"C:\Users\MCPEG\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MCPEG\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How do i Fix this?

I tried to Read the Discord.ext.forms docs and also the discord py docs but i couldnt help myself..

i also tried some samples from discord.ext.forms but they dont seem to work

Answer (score 0):

`message.edit` only takes kwargs, so you'd do `await message.edit(content="Timeout!")`

Comment: but where is timeout? i postet the whole code exept imports and token ‍♂️